# Docker: HTTPS Proxy with LetsEncrypt

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm trying to make a secure docker proxy as a proof of concept. This seems like it's close to working (port 80 works and the "It Works!" page comes up for b.example.com). However, the console shows an error on generating keys.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes:
     - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    volumes_from:
     - nginx-proxy:rw
    environment:
      - LETSENCRYPT_TEST=true

  site-b:
    image: httpd
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
      - back
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=1234
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=b.example.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=b.example.com
```

**Error**:

> nginx-letsencrypt_1  | 2018-04-27 11:41:40,244:ERROR:simp_le:1446: CA marked some of the authorizations as invalid, which likely means it could not access http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/X. Did you set correct path in -d example.com:path or --default_root? Are all your domains accessible from the internet? Please check your domains' DNS entries, your host's network/firewall setup and your webserver config. If a domain's DNS entry has both A and AAAA fields set up, some CAs such as Let's Encrypt will perform the challenge validation over IPv6. If your DNS provider does not answer correctly to CAA records request, Let's Encrypt won't issue a certificate for your domain (see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/caa/). Failing authorizations: https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/HsDmBtfcqucZ2j7gT5rGkCf1ESqHaxbkNxZRRWwXfFQ

Comment: I’m not sure if this is the problem, but for Let’s Encrypt to give you a certificate to a domain, you have to have control of that domain when accessed from the internet.

Comment: I do have my host file setup for that url to point back to my machine, and I'm running docker from my own machine as well.

Comment: Have you checked whethere any **outside** server (as in: not in your local network) can access your internal Docker machines?